# rails, model validation from nested model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, model, associations

I have a Post model and Comment model (Post has_many comments, Comment belongs_to Post)

I want to validate a field in my Comment model where they can only create/update if a comment field is less than the difference between 2 Post date_fields. How do I go about achieving this?

Right now, in my Comment model, I have:

```
validates :comment_check, presence: true, :numericality => { :greater_than_or_equal_to => 0 }
```

I just need to add the validation to make it :less_than_or_equal_to the Post date diff. I also have this model method in my Post model:

```
def self.days_diff
  (end_date.to_date - start_date.to_date).to_i
end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Comment Model you can validate with:

```
validate :comment_date

def comment_date
  if self.post.end_date < Time.now or self.post.start_date.to_date > Time.now
    self.errors.add(:created_at, "failed to save at the moment")
  end
end
```

Comment: awesome! I adjusted a few of the variable names, but syntax was spot on. Thanks JB!